# Is there a way to prevent a text box from accepting letters?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which gives an error message if you type anything that isn't a number:

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox3.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Only digits (0-9) allowed."
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that if I were to type a letter in the box, it gives me the error message but still writes the letter in the box. I want the code to completely prevent input from anything that isn't numerical.

Comment: Is this on a userform?

Comment: @SJR, Yes, and it's ActiveX.

Comment: Note that `IsNumeric` will return True for characters other than 0-9. In this specific context, trailing spaces, trailing `+` or `-` signs, decimal separators and thousands separators will all be accepted by IsNumeric. Other combinations also work as a whole (e.g. `10e5`) but would fail in this context when built up character by character (e.g. `10e` fails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the KeyPress event to stop any non-numeric entries in the first place.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

If Not (KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57) Then
    KeyAscii = 0
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the value in the Text Box.

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox3.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Only digits (0-9) allowed."
        TextBox3.Value = ""
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Or if you don't want to remove everything you can remove the last character entered.

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox3.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Only digits (0-9) allowed."
        TextBox3.Value = Left(TextBox3.Value,Len(TextBox3.Value) - 1)
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Steven Carlson: Thanks! However I'd like to keep any previous digits in the textbox before the letter is typed in.

Answer (score 0):

u can use keydown event

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
   If Not IsNumeric(Chr(KeyCode)) Then
      KeyCode = 0
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the KeyPress Event

```
Private Sub TextBox3_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.KeyPress
    Dim sKeys As String = "1234567890"
    If Not sKeys.Contains(e.KeyChar.ToString()) Then e.Handled = True
End Sub
```